# How can I get the current category id in function.php in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories

I want to use current category id in ajax script and I have used the following.

```
<?php  echo  get_cat_ID(single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?>
```

This works in category page but not in function.php then how can I get current category id in function.php in any other way ? If I will get current category id then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

We can get current category id by using 
`get_the_category( int $id = false )`

**Parameters:**
$id(int) (Optional) default to current post ID. The post ID. Default value: false

**Return:** (array) Array of WP_Term objects, one for each category assigned to the post.

**Example:**

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );
}
```

**Reference:** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/